# Assignment operator `=` in python

Tags: python

If I have three variables, such as `x,y,z=1,2,3`, I can use `x=y=z` but can't use `x=(y=z)` in python. What's difference between `x=y=z` and `x=(y=z)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y=z` is an *assignment statement*, not an *expression* (as it is in, say, C). It can only be used where a statement is expected. You can't, for instance, do `print(y=z)`. So `x=(y=z)` is grammatically ill-formed.

`x=y=z` is a single assignment, not a combination of two assignments. The grammar specifically allows targets to be chained in an assignment statement. The relevant grammar bit:

```
assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (expression_list | yield_expression)
```

Comment: `assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (expression_list | yield_expression)` just has one assignment operator, why you say it can be chained?

Comment: @gaussclb: The `+` means "one or more" of the thing the `+` is attached to.

Comment: Do you mean `assignment_stmt ::= (target_list "=")+ (expression_list | yield_expression | assignment_stmt)`?

Comment: No, that's not the correct grammar. As userblahblah explained, the `+` means that there can be multiple `target_list =`s chained in a single expression. `target_list = target_list = target_list = expression_list`.

Answer (score 1):

`x=y=z` assigns `x` and `y` the value stored in `z`.

```
In [133]: z = 5

In [134]: x = y = z

In [135]: x
Out[135]: 5

In [136]: y
Out[136]: 5
```

`x=(y=z)` wants to assign to `x` the outcome of the expression in the parenthesis. Unfortunately, the expression `y=z` is not evaluated this way in Python within the parenthesis.

```
In [137]: x=(y=z)
  File "<ipython-input-137-445a19ecd607>", line 1
    x=(y=z)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If on the otherhand, you were looking to assign the result of the equivalency test of "is `y` equal to `z`", then you could do so with the following:

`x=(y == z)`

```
In [138]: x = (y == z)

In [139]: x
Out[139]: True

In [140]: y
Out[140]: 5

In [141]: z
Out[141]: 5
```